# json serializer NullValueHandling without use datamember attribute

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-web-api

In my Web api project, Right now I'm skipping null values. therefore, the return json ignores null values and prints the property.

In Global.asax file:

```
//manage the null in the response
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```

However, I want to replace the null values by "-". but, i dont want to use data member attribute for each property...

```
[DefaultValue("-")].
```

i have more than 10 classes in my project... so, It is not the most elegant solution.

I wish were a simple solution and apply to any conversion, as does with null values from the Global.asax

Example.

```
public class User
{
    public string user { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string dni { get; set; }
}
```

when exists all data, my service return

```
{
  "user": "usertest",
  "name": "nametest",
  "dni": "123456789"
}
```

But, when dni, doesn't exists, respond this

```
{
  "user": "usertest",
  "name": "nametest",
  "dni": ""
}
```

So, I would like to respond as follows

```
{
  "user": "usertest",
  "name": "nametest",
  "dni": "-"
}
```

Comment: Would you mind clarifying your question a little?  Do you mean you want to skip writing members whose current value matches their default value, or, when writing a member with a null value, replace the written value with the default value?

Comment: Also, do you mean that you don't want to use the `[DefaultValue]` for each property?  [`DefaultValueAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not a data member attribute, it's used for many things including property editors.

Comment: ok, edited. i dont wanto to use default attribute. [DefaultValue("-")]. i just need a simple and elegant way to json serializer set DefaultValue for all properties.

Comment: Would you mind creating a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem?  I'm having some trouble understanding what you want to do even after the question edit.  Do you want to 1) **Convert** null values to "-" values?  2) **Skip** members whose value is `"-"`?  3) Convert null values of *string-valued properties only only* to `"-"`?

Comment: @dbc i want to 1) Yes!

Comment: Do you want 1) or 3)  I.e. if you have properties `public int? Value { get; set; }` and `public SomeClass { get; set; }` that are both null, should they appear as `"-"`?  Because if they do, the JSON will not be deserializable.  Again, a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your problem would help.

Comment: @dbc no, all properties are strings

Comment: @dbc edited with example.

Comment: `""` isn't a null value, it's an empty string.  A null value would look like `null`, with no quotes.  See http://json.org/.  So, do you want to remap empty strings, or null strings?

Comment: @dbc yes, `""` isn't a null value, return `""` because i set the propertiy with string.empty. but i have to do this with all properties and i don't have to. i just wanna do one time for all properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this with a custom `IContractResolver`.  The resolver can apply an `IValueProvider` to each and every string property, which would then handle the conversion of null values to `-` (and back, if you are deserializing the same JSON).

Here is the code you would need for the resolver:

```
public class NullStringReplacementResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> props = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        // Attach a NullStringReplacementProvider instance to each string property
        foreach (JsonProperty prop in props.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop.UnderlyingName);
            if (pi != null)
            {
                prop.ValueProvider = new NullStringReplacementProvider(pi);
            }
        }

        return props;
    }

    protected class NullStringReplacementProvider : IValueProvider
    {
        PropertyInfo targetProperty;

        public NullStringReplacementProvider(PropertyInfo targetProperty)
        {
            this.targetProperty = targetProperty;
        }

        // GetValue is called by Json.Net during serialization.
        // The target parameter has the object from which to read the string;
        // the return value is the string that gets written to the JSON
        public object GetValue(object target)
        {
            // if the value of the target property is null, replace it with "-"
            string s = (string)targetProperty.GetValue(target);
            return (s == null ? "-" : s);
        }

        // SetValue gets called by Json.Net during deserialization.
        // The value parameter has the original value read from the JSON;
        // target is the object on which to set the value.
        public void SetValue(object target, object value)
        {
            // if the value in the JSON is "-" replace it with null
            string s = (string)value;
            targetProperty.SetValue(target, s == "-" ? null : s);
        }
    }
}
```

To use the custom resolver, you need to add it to the `JsonSerializerSettings` that are used during serialization and deserialization.  If you're using ASP.NET Web API, you can do that by adding the following to the `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
var settings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
settings.ContractResolver = new NullStringReplacementResolver();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FVA3p8

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend doing this.  The problem is that if one if your string-value properties happens to have the same value as your "null value" `"-"`, you will lose information when serializing, namely whether or not the property was actually null.

That being said, you can do this with a [`ContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) by overriding the [`JsonProperty.ValueProvider`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_ValueProvider.htm) for string-valued properties:

```
public class StringRemappingContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    static readonly object NullValue;

    static StringRemappingContractResolver() { NullValue = new object(); }

    readonly Dictionary<object, object> map;
    readonly ILookup<object, object> reverseMap;

    public StringRemappingContractResolver() : this(new KeyValuePair<object, object> [] { new KeyValuePair<object, object>(null, "-")}) 
    {
    }

    public StringRemappingContractResolver(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object, object>> map)
    {
        if (map == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("map");
        this.map = map.ToDictionary(p => p.Key ?? NullValue, p => p.Value);
        this.reverseMap = map.ToLookup(p => p.Value ?? NullValue, p => p.Key);
    }

    class StringRemappingValueProvider : IValueProvider
    {
        readonly IValueProvider baseProvider;
        readonly Dictionary<object, object> map;
        readonly ILookup<object, object> reverseMap;

        public StringRemappingValueProvider(IValueProvider baseProvider, Dictionary<object, object> map, ILookup<object, object> reverseMap)
        {
            if (baseProvider == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("baseProvider");
            this.baseProvider = baseProvider;
            this.map = map;
            this.reverseMap = reverseMap;
        }

        #region IValueProvider Members

        public object GetValue(object target)
        {
            var value = baseProvider.GetValue(target);
            object mapped;
            if (map.TryGetValue(value ?? NullValue, out mapped))
                value = mapped;
            return value;
        }

        public void SetValue(object target, object value)
        {
            foreach (var mapped in reverseMap[value ?? NullValue])
            {
                // Use the first.
                value = mapped;
                break;
            }
            baseProvider.SetValue(target, value);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            property.ValueProvider = new StringRemappingValueProvider(property.ValueProvider, map, reverseMap);
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
public class User
{
    public string user { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string dni { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new StringRemappingContractResolver() };

        var user = new User { user = "usertest", name = "nametest", dni = null };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, settings);
        Debug.WriteLine(json); // Prints {"user":"usertest","name":"nametest","dni":"-"}
        Debug.Assert(JToken.DeepEquals(JToken.Parse(json), JToken.Parse(@"{'user':'usertest','name':'nametest','dni':'-'}"))); // No assert
        var userBack = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json, settings);
        Debug.Assert(user.dni == userBack.dni && user.name == userBack.name && user.user == userBack.user); // No assert
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

<del>You can register a converter in the globals.asax.  You would add something like this:</del>

<del>config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.add(new NullHandlerConverter());</del>

<del>Where, NullHandlerConverter is a custom converter that you will need to write.</del>

**Edit**: Brian is right.  Converters cannot be used since there is no way to have them called on `null` values.

Comment: Unfortunately, a `JsonConverter` won't work for this, because a converter doesn't get called for null values during serialization.  Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LmcroE