# Json.net ContractResolver

Tags: c#, json.net

How to find out if called from Serializiaton or deserialization ?

I need something like this:

```
protected override IValueProvider CreateMemberValueProvider(MemberInfo member)
{
    IValueProvider valueProvider = base.CreateMemberValueProvider(member);

    if (member.CustomAttributes.First().AttributeType == typeof(EncryptedAttribute))
    {
        object value = valueProvider.GetValue(_object);
        if(IsInSerialization())
        {
            valueProvider.SetValue(_object, Encrypt(value));
        }
        else
        {
            valueProvider.SetValue(_object, Decrypt(value));
        }
    }
    return valueProvider;
}
```

Comment: You have no way to know this from within the contract resolver itself, especially since the contracts are shared between serialization and deserialization.  You could 1) Use a different resolver for serialization and deserialization, or 2) [`IValueProvider`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IValueProvider.htm) anyway has both `SetValue` and `GetValue`, you could do the correct thing in each.  Related: [How can I encrypt selected properties when serializing my objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29196809/3744182).

Comment: @dbc i guess 2) is the most handy. how would I change the IValueProvider for the selected property ?

Comment: Well the linked question [How can I encrypt selected properties when serializing my objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29196809/3744182) shows exactly how.  Another example of a custom value provider can be see in [NewtonSoft JsonConverter - Access other properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47872645)

Comment: @dbc yeah true.. i seem to be blind. Thanks for your help - it's working perfectly. if u feel like posting that as an answer or closing as a dupe im down !

Comment: And also: [*Overriding a property value in custom JSON.net contract resolver*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46977905) and [this answer to *Json Convert empty string instead of null*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35620248).  Can this be closed off as a dup, or do you need more specific help?

Comment: OK, done.  Glad to help.